# C++: Pointers value & addresses

Tags: c++, pointers

So I have the following code:

```
char userLoginName[] = "Smith";
char password[] = "Smith";
char *_userLoginName, *_password;

_userLoginName = &userLoginName[0]; //1st way
_password = password; //2nd way
```

Would I be doing the same thing in the two last lines? If not, then why and when would/should I use each of these methods?

EDIT#1: I put the two of them on cout and I had the same result. I don't know how to differentiate them.

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-array-name-a-pointer-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are basically the same. Arrays when used as rvalues decay into pointers to the first element, so the expression `_password = password;` is implicitly converted to `_password = &password[0];`

Comment: I see, that answer my question.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, these two examples are the same.  The array `password` decays to a pointer to its first element in your second example, so they're semantically identical.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting the same output for both is that they both point to the same literal (not exactly the same address, though).

Suppose you had this:

```
char userLoginName[] = "Smithlogin"; 
char password[] = "Smithpass"; 
char *_userLoginName, *_password;

_userLoginName = &userLoginName[0]; //1st way
_password = password; //2nd way
```

You'd have different outputs for _userLoginName and _password.

The array name is actually a pointer. So userLoginName is a pointer to the first element to an array of chars.

So for the [] operator. Say you have and array called arr. arr[x] is actually *(arr + x). It moves the pointer by the specified amount to point to what you want and dereferences it.

Your two methods of assigning a pointer do essentially the same thing if they are operating on the same array though, but only because you're looking at element 0.

Comment: All of this is pretty good, except for the part where you say an array is a pointer, which it isn't.

Comment: All is great, but I made them equal because that was the intent. I was wondering if doing something `_password = password;` would simply copy the value or also refer to the same address. Therefore my two examples with different names but same content.

Comment: An array as a data structure is not a pointer, but the representation of the label associated is a pointer. The structure of the label has a bit more than just a pointer in some instances, but you can make an array C-style using malloc.